# Making editable table work cross-browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cross-browser

I've been working on an ASP.NET page containing a `ListView`. When the user clicks a row, the content of the last (visible) column of this (once parsed) HTML `table` is replaced with a textbox (by means of jQuery), making the value editable.

So far, this works like a charm in Chrome but no joy in IE10.

In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wimombelets/fSqkZ/), the value becomes editable but then the Save button doesn't work as expected.

In IE the textbox doesn't appear. Funny detail: if I comment out the four vars (`invNr`, `newInvNr`, `oldHtml` and `spanWidth`), the `input` element *DOES* appear in IE10 but of course I have no data to work with. Really REALLY weird.

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr[id*="itemRow"]').click(function () {
        $clickedRow = $(this);

        //this makes sure the input field isn't emptied when clicked again
        if ($clickedRow.find('input[id$="editInvNr"]').length > 0) {
            return;
        }

        var invNr = $clickedRow.find('span[id$="InvoiceNumber"]').text(),
            newInvNr = '',
            oldHtml = $clickedRow.find('span[id$="InvoiceNumber"]').html(),
            spanWidth = $clickedRow.find('span[id$="InvoiceNumber"]').width();

        $clickedRow.find('span[id$="InvoiceNumber"]').parent('td').html('<input type="text" ID="editInvNr"></input>');
        $clickedRow.find('input[id="editInvNr"]').val(invNr).focus().on('input propertychange', function () {
            $clickedRow.find('span[id$="SaveResultMsg"]').hide();
            $clickedRow.find('td[id$="SaveOption"]').show();
            $clickedRow.find('input[id*="btnSaveInvNrFormat"]').show();
            newInvNr = $(this).val();
            if (newInvNr == $clickedRow.find('span[id$="InvoiceNumber"]').text()) {
                $clickedRow.find('td[id$="SaveOption"]').hide();
            }
        });
    });

    $('tr[id*="itemRow"]').focusout(function () {
        $rowLosingFocus = $(this);
        var previousValue = $rowLosingFocus.find('input[id$="editInvNr"]').val();
        $rowLosingFocus.find('input[id$="editInvNr"]').closest('td').html('<asp:Label ID="lblInvoiceNumber" runat="server" />');
        $rowLosingFocus.find('span[id$="InvoiceNumber"]').text(previousValue);
    });
});

function UpdateInvoiceNrFormat(leButton) {
    $buttonClicked = $(leButton);
    $buttonClicked.focus();

    var companyName = $buttonClicked.closest('tr').find('span[id$="lblCompanyName"]').text(),
        invoiceType = $buttonClicked.closest('tr').find('span[id$="lblInvoiceType"]').text(),
        invNrFormat = $buttonClicked.closest('tr').find('span[id$="lblInvoiceNumber"]').text();

    PageMethods.UpdateInvoiceNumberFormat(companyName, invoiceType, invNrFormat, onSuccess, onError);
    function onSuccess(result) {
        $buttonClicked.hide();
        $buttonClicked.siblings('span[id$="SaveResultMsg"]').text(result).show();
    }
    function onError(result) {
        $buttonClicked.hide();
        $buttonClicked.siblings('span[id$="SaveResultMsg"]').text('Error:' + result).show();
    }
}
```

I've tried various combinations of jQuery statements, chaining and avoiding chaining, placing it at the bottom of the page as someone suggested, commenting out various parts of the code out of sheer desperation. Still nada.

Comment: I had a quick look but when the focus is lost on the edit box, the element is replaced with `<asp:Label ID="lblInvoiceNumber" runat="server" />` which will not show up on the client. Also, `id` should be unique and there are multiple `id="btnSaveInvNrFormat"`on the page - this is very likely to be the cause of the problem since jQuery will get confused trying to find an element by (unique) id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no way to make the `html()` method replace the html correctly in IE10, although I never did find out exactly why. I ended up writing both elements into the table cell, set `style="display:none"` for one of them and use `show()` / `hide()` and that's good enough for me (and apparently for IE10 as well).

For anyone encountering the same issue: this is a **workaround**, not a solution in the strictest sense.